# application enter in background IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

There's a way to notify a object when the method "**applicationDidEnterBackground**" of application delegate is called but just getting the applicationObject.

I need to do some action when application get on background but I just have access to the application object through "**[UIApplication sharedApplication]**".

Note: I need those 3 methods applicationWillTerminate, applicationWillEnterForeground, applicationDidEnterBackground but I can't access to applicationDelegate methods.

Comment: These methods should all be in `AppDelegate.m`. Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: Morgan is right, all these methods are available in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: Morgan is right but I can't access to those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to inform your class that these methods are being called.
In the init register the the correct notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminateNotification:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```

This will call a method this method, which you will have to add in you class:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminateNotification::(NSNotification *)notifictaion{
}
```

The notification that you want to add are: `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`, `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`

**Don't** forget to unregistered the you class instance  in the `dealloc` of you class, even in ARC:

```
-(void) dealloc {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. My solution was to get the instance of AppDelegate and register my object as observer:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate addApplicationDidEnterBackgroundObserver:myobject];
// and later...
[appDelegate removeObserver:myobject];
```

sure the solution by rckoenes is more elegant.